# Converting psql text column to tsvector

Tags: postgresql, psql

I'm trying to convert a text column to tsvector, using a Rails migration:

```
change_column :people, :title, "tsvector USING title::tsvector"
```

It's getting caught up on special characters such as:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error in tsvector: "Project Manager: Software"
```

For some reason if I update the column, by say adding a space to the end, and rerun them migration, it works.

Any ideas why? So far it's happened with fields tat contain: :, &, í

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`to_tsvector()` is for converting plain text to a tsvector.

`::tsvector` is for asserting that the given text is already a valid representation of a tsvector, which yours is not.

Comment: Thanks! Here's what I needed: change_column :people, :title, "tsvector USING to_tsvector(title)"

Comment: Can you give us an example on how does the `text` body look like that is convertible to vector?